# Shiny Bulbasaur doesn't have a golden bulb but Ivysaur and Venusaur do

Tags: pokemon

Shiny Bulbasaur doesn't have a golden/shiny bulb but Ivysaur and Venusaur do. Was that intentional, or did they realize that they should make the bulb shiny when they started drawing Ivysaur or Venusaur?

[image: Shiny Bulbasaur]
[image: Shiny Ivysaur]
[image: Shiny Venusaur]

```
^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Bulb  Bulbs are golden
isn't
golden
```

Comment: If you notice however the back of Bulbasaur blooms as it evolves, as such i was suspect that the golden bulb is inside the leaves on it back and when it evolves the leaves open up showing the bulb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the *seed* on shiny Ivysaur and Venusaur that is golden. While still a Bulbasaur, the bulb as yet to bloom and the seed is covered by the green leaves.

In [one episode](https://youtu.be/Jel0DjTP-C4?t=5) of the anime, it shows a Bulbasaur evolve into an Ivysaur. Albeit it's not shiny, you can clearly see the evolution process causes the bulb to bloom which reveals the seed on its back.

Answer (score 2):

In the original Gold/Silver games for Game Boy Color, shiny Pokemon were first introduced to the public as rare collectible versions that appear 1 in 8192 wild encounters.

But most people don't know this one thing about shiny Pokemon and their colors: **the developers didn't manually choose shiny Pokemon colors**.

All they did was **substitute each Pokemon sprite's colors with another suitable palette**, and they simply published whatever came out of the other end of that substitution, rarely applying additional touch-ups. To achieve this, sometimes they **passed each pixel of the sprites through *bitwise filters or masks*, or inverted the colors to their complements**. Whatever method was used, the output of such operations was reflected in shiny Pokemon during the first 5 generations. Consequently, there's often a 1:1 match between the colors of shiny forms with their non-shiny counterparts.

(**Since Bulbasaur doesn't have a pink flower that's bloomed yet, its shiny form also lacks a golden flower.**)

This process set a precedent for how shiny Pokemon were "supposed" to look like. Since then, Pokemon has made *some* modifications, but many species present in much the same form as they did in their original forms from 2000.